# Ignoring duplicate entries to MySQL table when using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I can't get the below code to successfully prevent duplication when inserting data into the table:

```
<?php
   include('simple_html_dom.php');  
    // Create DOM from URL
   $html = file_get_html('http://thesite.com/example/');

   // Find all article blocks

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
    mysql_select_db("dataminer", $con);
   if (!$con)
    {
  die(mysql_error());
    }else {
   foreach($html->find('li.search-result') as $sitelisting){
 $escapedlisting = mysql_real_escape_string($sitelisting);
 $debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO extract (listing) VALUES ('$escapedlisting')");
    if (!$debugquery)
   {
   die(mysql_error());
  }
 }
 }
 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Despite the INSERT IGNORE, it's still duplicating every entry every time the script is ran.

**EDIT:** Fixed this by changing:

```
foreach($html->find('li.search-result') as $sitelisting){
     $escapedlisting = mysql_real_escape_string($sitelisting);
     $debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO extract (listing) VALUES ('$escapedlisting')");
```

to:

```
foreach($html->find('li.search-result') as $sitelisting){
    $item['address'] = mysql_real_escape_string($sitelisting->find('div.adr-flag', 0)->plaintext);
    $item['desc'] = mysql_real_escape_string($sitelisting->find('ul.attributes', 0)->plaintext);

    $debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO extract VALUES ('$item[address]', '$item[desc]')");
```

Comment: I don't have any reason unless "listing" is not the actual primary key.

Comment: Have you defined a `UNIQUE` index on `extract.listing`?

Comment: eggyal: the problem with that is it's a LONGTEXT type so I cannot make that the primary key or unique key. This script scrapes data from a website and then inserts it into the DB, so the content is always changing. I want it to check for duplicates every time it's ran.

Comment: You would be wise to store a hash of your `LONGTEXT` value in a `UNIQUE` indexed column.

Comment: Thanks. You reminding me of the need for a primary key allowed me to re-think how I was going about doing this. I've placed my code changes above and all is working well.